# Edit text view with image and text wrapped around image

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, spannablestring, spannable

I am building a rich text editor. 
I have implemented text formatting like bold italic etc and also paragraph formatting like blockQuote. Now I would like to add images in editor and text should wrap around it. 
I have implemented all these using `SpannableString()` and `Spanned()` and `StyleSpan()`.

I can add image to a line using `ImageSpan()`, but that add it inline and its just there in place of a character
, what I want is to insert it in paragraph and rest of text should wrap around it. I am able to add image at the beginning of text by following code.. but I cannot align it center and right.

```
 SpannableString string = new SpannableString("Text with icon and padding");
 string.setSpan(new IconMarginSpan(bitmap, 30), 0, string.length(),
 Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

How to do it ? any example? or what procedure to follow?

Comment: Can you provide an image prototype? So that I can exactly understand you issue.

Answer (score 2):

you can fulfill your requirement like below:

you can set your image in imageview and your text in **Html.fromHtml("here put your text")**

**gradle** file:

```
compile 'com.github.deano2390:FlowTextView:2.0.5'
```

your **XML** layout:

```
<uk.co.deanwild.flowtextview.FlowTextView
    android:id="@+id/ftv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="400dip"
            android:padding="10dip"
            android:src="@drawable/android2"/>

</uk.co.deanwild.flowtextview.FlowTextView>
```

your **java** file:

```
FlowTextView flowTextView = (FlowTextView) findViewById(R.id.ftv);
             Spanned html = Html.fromHtml("here put your text");
             flowTextView.setText(html);
```

you may get help by this link https://github.com/deano2390/FlowTextView also

I hope it help you..!

Answer (score 1):

As per details given by you, It seems you might be using native EditText or you are trying with your custom EditText. Please provide this details to get exact solution of your query.

Apart from that, To build Rich Text Editor with the features mentioned by you (like Bold, Italic, Quote and Images etc), you can use this library RichEditor for Android: https://github.com/wasabeef/richeditor-android. It provides many features which may interest you.

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
EditText text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.text);
text.setCompoundDrawables(null, null, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.check_box), null);
```